# Could not update model's data using django

Tags: python, django

I am hoping when i make a query using form, then the model `SearchAllStatics`'s `view_count` would add one. But the fact is, it just still be one.

Here's the models.py

```
class SearchAllStatistic(models.Model):

    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-view_count']
```

views.py

```
class SearchWord(generic.View):

    def get(self, request):
        word = request.GET['field3']
        object = SearchAllStatistic.objects.filter(content=word)

        if object:
            w = SearchAllStatistic.objects.get(content=word)
            w.view_count =+1
            print(w.view_count)
            w.save()
        else:
            w = SearchAllStatistic(content=word, view_count=10)
            w.save()
        try:
            form = Search_Shiwen_Form(request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                shiwen = Shiwen.objects.get(field3=form.cleaned_data['field3'])
                return render(request, 'search/shiwen.html', {'result': shiwen})
            else:
                return render(request, 'search/errors.html', {'errors': 'xx'})
        except:
            form = Search_word_Form(request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                word = Newgw.objects.filter(field2=form.cleaned_data['field3'])
                return render(request, 'search/word.html', {'result': word})
            else:
                return render(request, 'search/errors.html')
```

Here's the template

```
<form id="form" method="GET" action="word/">
    <label for="id_field3"></label><input id="id_field3" maxlength="255" name="field3" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">xxx</button>
</form>
```

I would like to know why the view_count haven't been updated and just the just as `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake

```
    w.view_count =+1
```

which is assigning of `1` value to `view_count` variable instead of

```
    w.view_count += 1
```

which is using of `+=` operator what you want to do actually